# React & .Net Core Web API: Axios API showing status 'Pending'. unable to get desired data

Tags: reactjs, linq, .net-core, axios, webapi

When I call GET Api, in server application it gets data and return value but at client side I'm getting status 'Pending'. If I remove (I tried to remove .Include(c => c.__COM_Policy_SubCategory)) any of the subquery it works fine.

Reducer function:

```
export const assignment_list = () => (dispatch) => {
api.assignment()
.assignment_list()
.then((response)=>{
    dispatch({
        type : GET_ASSIGNMENTS,
        payload : response.data
    })
})
```

}

LINQ query:

```
List<COM_Ass> listCOM_Ass = await _dbContext.COM_Ass

                
                .Include(c => c.__COM_Ass_Pro).ThenInclude(cs => cs.COM_Procedure).ThenInclude(cs => cs.__COM_Procedure_Test)
                
                .Include(n => n.__COM_Ass_Exm).ThenInclude(user => user.UT_Admin_User)
                .Include(n => n.__COM_Ass_Eva)
                .Include(c => c.__COM_Policy_SubCategory)

                .ToListAsync();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQnju.png)
This image show request status is pending.